# How do I create a new folder with a increment number using Windows batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I increment a folder name using Windows batch command?

I have multiple folders at some path in a particular format like Release Version(1.060)
I want to create new folder with name - Release Version(1.063)

Comment: 1. Why did you roll back the nice edit? 2. What have you tried, where are you stuck? 3. Why the tag [tag:window]? do you mean [tag:windows]? 4. Consider to use another language than batch scripting due to quite limited arithmetic functions...

Answer (score 0):

list the folders (`/b` = name only, `/ad` = folders only, `/on` = sort by name), get the version number with a `for /f` loop, add one to the minor number (note the trick to handle leading zeros: add a `1` in front of it, add one and get the last three chars). Then simply reassemble the new version number:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=(.)" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /on "Release Version*"') do (
  set "major=%%a
  set "minor=1%%b"
)
set /a minor+=1
set "minor=%minor:~-3%"
echo new release version is "%major%.%minor%"
md "Release Version(%major%.%minor%)"
```

Of course, this depends on the exact format: `Release Version(x.yyy)`.

Comment: Not working. It displays an error - Parameter format not correct - ""Release Version*"".
and creating Release Version(.1) folder. Also can you explain me this part of code - "minor=%minor:~-3%"

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you put it into a `(`command block`)`? Then you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). -  `set "minor=%minor:~-3%"` sets the variable to the last three characters (cutting the leading `1`)

Comment: sorry, spotted a missing space. Seems to got lost by editing `:/` Try edited code.

Comment: Yes ,i realized the mistake and fixed it now its working fine..thanks a lot